# How to write a recursive OCL query with mixed classifiers?

Tags: emf, ocl

I've got an EMF metamodel as described below:

```
class Application
  - runsOn: Host [0..*]

interface Host

class VirtualMachine implements Host
  - runsOn: Host [0..*]

class PhysicalMachine implements Host
```

**The question I want to answer using OCL is:** find all `PhysicalMachine`s on which a given `Application` actually runs (directly or transitively). Please note that all of the following paths can occur in the instance model:

```
- Application runsOn PhysicalServer
- Application runsOn VirtualMachine runsOn PhysicalServer
- Application runsOn VirtualMachine runsOn VirtualMachine runsOn PhysicalServer
- ...
```

I imagine that this could somehow be expressed using the `closure` operator of OCL but I can't quite figure out the correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of tinkering, I think I've found an answer.

```
self.runsOn->asSet()
    ->closure(host: Host | 
        if host.oclIsKindOf(VirtualMachine) then 
            host.oclAsType(VirtualMachine).runsOn 
        else
            host->asSet() 
        endif
    )
```

This appears to work. Please correct me if the above  query is wrong or inefficient.

**Edit:** Thanks to the comment by Ed Willink below I have simplified the above query to:

```
self.runsOn->closure(host: Host | host->selectByKind(VirtualMachine).runsOn)
```

Comment: The outer -<asSet() is probably redundant since Application:runOn is probably unique.

Comment: The outer ->asSet() is probably redundant since Application:runsOn is probably unique. The inner asSet() is inefficient since it invites a recursion to host which has already been accumulated; the only-visit once check ensures that the closure is not infinite; Set{} would be better. If you are after lexical efficiency runsOn->closure(host | host->selectByKind(VirtualMachine).runsOn) is more compact.